# Google Data Studio Date Issue

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to generate report from Google Data Studio where i am using BigQuery As Connector, i want to change my Time Zone As per My Location (Current Time and date) but not as per BigQuery Time zone, 
is there any Chance do this in Google Data Studio.

Comment: what is the current timestamp behavior ? UTC or GMT

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like

```
DATE(timestamp,"Asia/Kolkata") as Timestamp
```

or
You can use Bigquery, the 2nd argument of the TIMESTAMP() function to convert UTC timestamp to your local time zone

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2020-02-24 13:30:00", "Asia/Kolkata") AS timestamp_in_IST;
```

[Here is the supported timezone by Big query](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Time-Zone-Values_66194188)

Comment: This URL seems to be broken. :(

Answer (score 1):

The functionality (Time Zone calculations) is now available in Google Data Studio, with the introduction of additional Date Time functions in the [17 Sep 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020). Using [Mohit's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60371770/12892553) example; where the goal is to convert the Date Time field (titled `Date_Field` in this Report) from the default (UTC) to `Asia/Kolkata` (change the Time Zone as required), the following does the trick:

### 0) [Upgrade the Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63926419/12892553)

Ensure that the **Date Time** field has been upgraded to to the newer Date field type.

Added a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 1) `Asia/Kolkata`

```
PARSE_DATETIME(
    "%s",
    CAST(CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%s",DateField)AS NUMBER) - DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME("UTC"),CURRENT_DATETIME("Asia/Kolkata"), SECOND)AS TEXT))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/548d0ff7-61e6-4441-a4f8-6d82956e1d68) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]